# Сделать отступы между блоком и бордюром при наведение на блок css :hover

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, hover

**Всем добрый день!**

Есть чертёж с фигмы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его надо как то сформировать . И вот мои попытки:

```css
.group{
    background: #ebeff6;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width:260px;
    height: 382px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.group:hover{
  border: 5px solid #3894EB;;
    border-radius: 18px;
}
.group__img img{
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
}
.group__text{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #142D49;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 82px;
}
article{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="group__img">
      <img src="https://img1.freepng.ru/20180323/zsq/kisspng-bmw-car-audi-q5-logo-roundel-bmw-5ab51b5fe58e14.6872183715218184639403.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="group__text">
      Photos
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="group__img">
      <img src="https://static.truckersmp.com/avatarsN/2005067.1563686525.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="group__text">
      Photos
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Проблема в том, что не могу оставить отступы между блоками и бордюрами

Буду рад за любой ответ!

Comment: Для .group добавьте внутренний отступ - `padding: 5 px`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант с `:before`

```css
.group {
  background: #ebeff6;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 382px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.group:before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}

.group:hover:before {
  border-color: #3894EB;
}

.group__img img {
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
}

.group__text {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #142D49;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 82px;
}

article {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="group__img">
      <img src="https://img1.freepng.ru/20180323/zsq/kisspng-bmw-car-audi-q5-logo-roundel-bmw-5ab51b5fe58e14.6872183715218184639403.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="group__text">
      Photos
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <div class="group__img">
      <img src="https://static.truckersmp.com/avatarsN/2005067.1563686525.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="group__text">
      Photos
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.group_c {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  transition: border 1s;
}

.group {
  background: #ebeff6;
  width: 260px;
  height: 382px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.group_c:hover {
  border: 5px solid #3894EB;
}

.group__img img {
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.group__text {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #142D49;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 82px;
}

article {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="group_c">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group__img">
        <img src="https://img1.freepng.ru/20180323/zsq/kisspng-bmw-car-audi-q5-logo-roundel-bmw-5ab51b5fe58e14.6872183715218184639403.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="group__text">
        Photos
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group_c">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="group__img">
        <img src="https://static.truckersmp.com/avatarsN/2005067.1563686525.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="group__text">
        Photos
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
  .group {
    background: #ebeff6;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 382px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```